# Arrange an array of object base on the selected id

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to arrange my array base on the selected id
for example I have an array of `[{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}, {id:4}, {id:5}]`
and the selected array is [3,5];  the output will be `[{id:1}, {id:3}, {id:5}, {id:2}, {id:4}]`

I manage to get the right arrangement on `[3,5]` but the problem is inconsistent when I add/change value of selected array

```
var aData = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}];
var selectedId = [3,5];


let firstArray;

selectedId.forEach(function(id) {
    let iIndex = selectedId.indexOf(id);
    if (iIndex === 0) {
       firstArray = iIndex;
    }   
    array_move(aData, id-1, selectedId[firstArray]-2);
});

function array_move(arr, old_index, new_index) {
    if (new_index >= arr.length) {
        var k = new_index - arr.length + 1;
        while (k--) {
           arr.push(undefined);
        }
    }
    arr.splice(new_index, 0, arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
};
```

Comment: Is `{id:1}` supposed to be unmovable?

Comment: Whats the expected result?

Comment: @CarlBinalla it can be move if its selected for instance i can move it to the second index

Comment: I was expecting that when the selected array is `[3, 5]`, the result would be `[{id:3}, {id:5}, {id:1}, {id:2}, {id:4}]` rather than `[{id:1}, {id:3}, {id:5}, {id:2}, {id:4}]`

Comment: @MaZoli it varies in the selected array  what I was actually trying to do is  I have a table. the table has checkboxes and basing on which checkboxes are check I have a button which is move to the top, move up, move down, move to the bottom

Comment: @CarlBinalla I am actually basing to the first index of selectedId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it.

```
let output =aData.filter(obj => selectedId.indexOf(obj.id) > -1).concat(aData.filter(obj => selectedId.indexOf(obj.id) ==-1))
console.log(output)
```

If you want to maintain the ordering of the selectedId array, you can first apply reduce on the selectedId array to get the  selected items from aData.

Then concat the result with elements of aData not present in selectedId.

```
let output = selectedId.reduce((arr,elem) =>{
  let elemIndex = aData.findIndex(obj => obj.id === elem)
   if(elemIndex > -1){
     arr.push(aData[elemIndex])
   }
   return arr
},[])
let finalOutput = output.concat(aData.filter(obj => selectedId.indexOf(obj.id) == -1))
console.log(finalOutput)
```

Comment: This would give you a new array with the arrangement

Comment: These does arrange correctly for [3,5] but for instance I have selected an Id of [1,5,4] it arrange them in numerical order.  [1,4,5,2,3] the desire output will be [1,5,4,2,3]

Comment: Sorry, I was out on weekends. These works BTW thankss, you save my life!

Answer (score 1):

`filter` first, then `concat`:

```js
var aData = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}];
var selectedId = [3,5];

aData = aData.filter(({ id }) => selectedId.includes(id)).concat(aData.filter(({ id }) => !selectedId.includes(id)));

console.log(aData);
```

Comment: the output is similar to anurag but this shouldn't arrange the output to numerical .  [1,5,4] it arrange them in numerical order. [1,4,5,2,3] the desire output will be [1,5,4,2,3]. These is a great help btw Thanks!